# Cannot find module '@app/core' - alias with jest and nodejs

Tags: node.js, webpack, jestjs, alias, nestjs

I am trying to run jest from a runner with nestjs and node.js and got the following error
and did not manage to run a test with a custom alias

```
        { Error: Cannot find module '@app/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

my jest-e2e.json that the jest run is configured as follows:

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": "..", // also tried '.'
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  },
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

app/core is defined in the tsconfig.json as follows:

```
    "paths": {
      "*": ["types/*"],
      "@app/*": ["*"]
    }
```

and working well in unit testing with jest:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/$1"
    },
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

Comment: What are exactly e2e tests? moduleNameMapper is essential here. That you have this error likely means that either jest-e2e.json is not applied, or tests do something that prevents module mapping to work, like child processes.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes I run the jest from an external library that acts as a test runner 
but i tried also to put this configuration inside the library hardcoded